# Can not start Docker 1.9.1

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I am a newbie about docker.
This morning I have just download and install docker 1.9.1 to my computer (OS: windows)

After install it, I run 'Docker Quickstart Terminal' but it fail
The console keep print like this:

```
Machine default already exists in VirtualBox.
Starting machine default...
(default) Starting VM...
Machine "default" was started.
Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-m
achine env` command.
Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): Regeneratin
g TLS certificates
Detecting the provisioner...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Setting environment variables for machine default...
Looks like something went wrong... Press any key to continue...
```

I have tried to remove the Virtual Machine and create it again, but the problem still happen

```
Creating Machine default...
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying C:\Users\mcthanh\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\U
sers\mcthanh\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Starting VM...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Machine is running, waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with boot2docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Checking connection to Docker...
Docker is up and running!
To see how to connect Docker to this machine, run: C:\Program Files\Docker Toolb
ox\docker-machine.exe env default
Setting environment variables for machine default...
Looks like something went wrong... Press any key to continue...
```

Do you have any exp about this? 
Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

After a sleep / wake cycle, Windows detects the Host-Only network as a "duplicate" and changes its IP. After that, docker-machine (or the Quickstart terminal) doesn't work anymore.

It is probably caused by this VirtualBox [bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9151) (from 5 years ago): so there doesn't seem to be a fix soon from VirtualBox. And it's probably a Windows bug.

This should be a valid workaround:

1. Open VirtualBox
2. Go to File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host-only Networks
3. Docker Toolbox probably created a second Host-only network, probably named "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter # 2", double click that
4. Change the "IPv4 Address" from something like 192.168.99.1 to something like 192.168.99.2 (you will probably have to increase / decrease the IP every time). But it's important that the IP actually changes.
5. Hit OK. If the IP changed (it should have changed), you will be prompted for you "Windows Administrator OK" (or however it's named).

After that, the docker-machine and the Quickstart Terminal should work.

Comment: The only true answer to solve the docker problem with VM! Thanks! :-D

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes we have virtualization disabled in our system make sure that
>   virtualization is enabled or not ?

follow given steps to check if u have virtualization enabled or not

```
Open Task manager
Click on performance
Click on CPU
Check whether virtualization is enabled or not
```

> If it is disabled then go to bios setting and enable it.